# Is there some known issue with Git Plugin 3.6.4 when integrating with private github repo through deploy_key?

Tags: git, jenkins, ssh

Even though I am able to successfully execute

```
ssh -T git@enterprisegithubdomain
```

on the terminal, it fails on when put in a jenkins BUILD shell. **Why ?**

This scenario is a route to my solving the problem of why the hostname comes unresolved everytime I build a jenkins project with SCM set as a private repo in above enterprisegithubdomain. I use

```
git@enterprisegithubdomain:organizationname/reponame.git
```

Comment: I don't get your problem.. please be more explicit.

Comment: @StephenKing The problem I am facing is that I am sitting in a VM spawned on a host registered in a VPN. So, now, I am trying to use my guest VM as jenkins server and hence, trying to connect to my enterprise github account. So, the connection works when tested on command line as seen BUT NOT when configured on jenkins using Git Plugin. Also, thank you for making my question more readable :-)